# WPF Listbox Bind to subproperty List of Objects

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I created a class named TestNumber which contains `public List<TestGroup> TestGroups {get; set;}`. The TestGroup class contains `public List<TestPackage> TestPackages {get; set;}` and `public property string Name {get; set;}`. The TestPackage class contains `public string Name {get; set;}`.

I have two list box. The first listbox which is bound to `TestGroups` list and it displays the `Name` of each `TestGroup`, this works as expected. For the second list box I would like to bind it to `TestPackages` list and have it display all `TestPackage` `Name` from all of the `TestGroup` with in the `TestGroups` list.

The data context is set in the code-behind as follow:

```
this.DataContext = TestNumber;
```

I tried the following code to bind the second listbox:

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestGroups/TestPackages}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

This displays all `Name` within `TestPackages` of only the first `TestGroup` within the `TestGroups` list.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestGroups}"
         Grid.Column="4"
         Grid.Row="1">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestPackages/Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This displays only the first `Name` within `TestPackages` of every `TestGroup` within the `TestGroups` list.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Through XAML, is it possible to populate the second list box with all `Name` within `TestPackages` within `TestGroups`? Are nested ListBox the only way (barring other controls) to accomplish this through XAML?

Comment: Have you forgotten to write what exacly your problem is? I can't find it.

Comment: @Hille Thank you for pointing this out. I edited the post to clearly state the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display all `TestPackages` in a single `ListBox`, you must define a property that actually returns all `TestPackages` somewhere.

Given your current setup, you can display all `TestPackages` for each `TestGroup` by using a nested `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestGroups}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestPackages}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I suspected I would have to define a property to return all TestPackages. Thank you for your help.